# Qt5: download a file without saving to HDD

Tags: qt, casting, qt5, qnetworkaccessmanager, qnetworkreply

I'm trying to download a file in Qt5, but the file must not be located on the HDD after download.
To clarify> My app will use a downloaded file to update some firmware, and I don't want the downloaded update to remain on the user's hard drive because it could get stolen.

So, I'm trying to make a `QFile` from `QNetworkReply*` but without saving it to some path on a hard drive.

I'm downloading a file using `QNetworkAccessManager` and storing the data into `QNetworkReply`. I always used to make a `QFile` with `QNetworkReply*`, but now I can't do that.

I have found the `QTemporaryFile` class where a file gets removed right after using it, but that still leaves user with some options of finding the file later.

I tried typecasting that `QNetworkReply*` as a `QFile`, but didn't manage to get that to work, seems like QFile can't be without a path on HDD.

Does anyone have any ideas how to do this, and how?

Thanks everyone.

Comment: How big is this file? What are you planning on doing with its contents?

Comment: <1 MB. It is supposed to be copied to a device (as a software update) via USB.
That's why I can't leave any trace because someone might steal my work.
You can check out my other questions to get an idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Again not sure your intended end use case but since your data is small enough to hold in memory you can use a [QByteArray](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbytearray.html) or [QBuffer](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbuffer.html) and write into it from your `QNetworkReply`. `QBuffer` provides a `QIODevice` interface for the `QByteArray` so it may be a bit easier for you to work with.

Make sure to open the `QBuffer` for read/write. See the simple example below from the Qt documentation, http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbuffer.html#details, below:

```
QBuffer buffer;
char ch;

buffer.open(QBuffer::ReadWrite);
buffer.write("Qt rocks!");
buffer.seek(0);
buffer.getChar(&ch);  // ch == 'Q'
buffer.getChar(&ch);  // ch == 't'
buffer.getChar(&ch);  // ch == ' '
buffer.getChar(&ch);  // ch == 'r'
```

That should allow you to read back the data and use as required without creating a file on the system.

Comment: Thank you, I managed to put all of the downloaded stuff into buffer, and then read back from it. Now I need to figure out how to send that buffer across different slots...

Again, thanks.

Comment: So, just to post the solution here...

I used QBuffer class, made a QBuffer* and sent it trough signals and slots, and everything appears to be working.

All the credit goes to @Matthew